# Unable to concatenate more than one value inside <a> tag in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a table which has a column with Name. I need to add the surname within brackets inside the Name column. Name is a hyperlink. When i add the surname between the  tag as below i am not able to see the surname value.Even the brackets inside the  tag are not displayed in the interface. but surname variable outside the  tag is displayed without any errors. Help me please.

```
<a nwf-elipsize-contents="{{row.entity[col.field]}}"
   data-abc-id="report-grid-{{col.field}}"
   title="{{row.entity[col.field]}}" 
   ng-href="{{ grid.appScope.getObjectLink(row.entity,col.field) }}">
  {{row.entity[col.field]}} ({{row.entity["surname"]}})
</a>
{{row.entity["surname"]}}
```

Comment: What does nwf-elipsize-contents does? My guess, based on the name, is that it takes what you pass in, and replaces it by a shorter text ending with ellipses if it's too lorge. Since you're not passing the surname, it only displays what you tell it to display.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! even if the surname is not passed the brackets should be displayed right? i tried using <span> and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<span>` elements:

```
<a ng-href="{{ grid.appScope.getObjectLink(row.entity,col.field) }}">
  <span nwf-elipsize-contents="{{row.entity[col.field]}}"
        data-abc-id="report-grid-{{col.field}}"
        title="{{row.entity[col.field]}}">     
    {{row.entity[col.field]}}
  </span>
  <span> ({{row.entity["surname"]}})</span>
</a>
{{row.entity["surname"]}}
```